# No puedo actualizar mi repositorio remoto de git

Tags: git, github

Buenas intento actualizar mi repositorio remoto de github subiendo los cambios que hice pero al hacerlo me sale este error, el comando utilizado fue git remote, la verdad que llevo poco tiempo manejado git

fatal: remote origin already exists.

Answer (score 1):

El comando `git remote` sólo se ejecuta la primera vez que inicializas un repositorio, es para vincular el repositorio remoto con el local, una vez vinculado ya no es necesario usar el comando si no tienes interés de cambiarlo.

Para poder subir tus cambios lo que necesitas hacer es usar la combinación básica de tres comandos en secuencia:

```
# Para indicar a GIT que tienes cambios para subir al repositorio.
git add .

# Para almacenar los cambios en tu repositorio.
git commit -m "Un mensaje que describa los cambios"

# Para enviar todos los cambios (commits existentes en el repositorio local) al repositorio remoto.
git push
```

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer intentaste actualizar en nombre de repositorio por un nombre que ya tienes.
Intenta con otro nombre si ese es tu objetivo.
Guíate con la documentación oficial de git para obtener más iformación.
https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente estás haciendo `**git remote add origin ...**`

En un repositorio el cual ya había un remote llamado "origin", quizá porque lo agregaste previamente, o porque lo clonaste (al clonar, se crea un remote llamado "origin")

Para ver los remotes usa: `**git remote -v**`

Si no corresponde al remote que quieres, puedes borrarlo con `**git remote remove origin**`

Otra opción es que agregues el nuevo remote con otro nombre: **`git remote add nuevoNombre ...**`